# Complete string matching

Tags: r

I have a vector of strings like for example `jk <- c("abc", "lkg", "mno", "ike")`
and a data frame `df` that looks like

```
names nos
 abc    1
 pqe    2
 mno    3
```

Where first I convert the string in the  `names` column to character strings by using `as.character(df$names)`

I want to check if the string in column is contained into vector `jk`
So, I wrote a function as below

```
res <- function(p) {
   if(grep(p, jk, fixed=TRUE) > 0) {
            return(1)
    else {
            return(0)
    }
}
```

The desired output should be as follows

```
names nos res
 abc    1   1
 pqe    2   0
 mno    3   1
```

But when I perform the following function call

```
df$res <- lapply(df$names, FUN=res)
```

I get the following error

> ```
> Error in if (grep(p, jk, fixed=TRUE) > 0) { : 
>   argument is of length zero
> ```

when I do the following function call

```
df$res <- apply(df$names, M FUN=res)
```

I get the following error.

> ```
> Error in apply(X = d$names, MARGIN = 1, FUN = res) : 
>   dim(X) must have a positive length
> ```

How do I get the desired output?
Please help!

Comment: `as.integer(df$names %in% jk)`

Comment: @Sotos I will try now doing that!! Regards!!

Comment: @Sotos Thanks It worked. I was not knowing about the operator

Comment: If you are looking for an exact match, `%in%` is the function to go with.

Comment: @Sotos do I need to delete the question as you have marked it duplicate? or do we keep it as is?

Comment: No keep it. It's now another reference point to redirect people to the duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159878/discussion-between-niranjan-agnihotri-and-sotos).